# 500 Internal Server Error Search REST API

Tags: search, spfx, spfx-webparts, search-api

I am trying to call search REST apis from an spfx webpart, but I am getting this:

> GET http://servername/_api/search/query?querytext=%27*%27

My code looks like this:

```
let query = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext=%27*%27`

this.context.spHttpClient.get(query, SPHttpClient.configuration.v1)
.then(response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  console.log(response) })
.catch(error => { console.log(error) })
```

I am testing the webpart using the workbench under _layouts, and I can verify that the query is valid, and I could paste it in browser and see the results, it just doesn't work from code.

**Update:**

I had a look at the logs (am using sp 2016 feature pack 2). and I saw this in the logs after I try to load my webpart:

> Parent=Request (GET:http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='*')
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

at

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Odata.ODataSerializeUtility.ConvertKeyValueToODataValue(String
>   key, Object value, ProxyContext proxyContext)

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried with out encode url  like `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext='*'`

Comment: Hi, yes I did same result.

Comment: Does it work in the browser?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott yes it works in the browser, but not from code.

Comment: can you share the network panel info from your browser?

Comment: @Arut here's a screenshot of the network tab: https://pasteboard.co/Hntmb4H.png

Comment: Click on the request which returns 500 internal server error and provide us another screenshot. Are you working in SharePoint On-prem? If so, may I know how many servers you have in your farm?

Comment: @Arut yes, this is on prem. here's a screenshot of the console in developer tools, and it shows the 500 internal server error: https://pasteboard.co/Hnz5JTA.png  When I click on the link for the request on the right side, I see this: https://pasteboard.co/Hnz5WKZ.png

Comment: can you click on the "query?querytext=...." from this screenshot https://pasteboard.co/Hntmb4H.png and show me what you see?

Answer (score 3):

You need add **SelectProperties** like as *'Title'* or other and it will work from code.

```
`&SelectProperties='Title'`
```